# Prestashop 1.7 disable cart poup

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am using prestashop 1.7 and want to disable the popup and instead call a custom javascript function that toggles my shopping cart visible.
I found various instructions, however I don't have a file called ps_shoppingcart.js. The only one I have is the ps_shoppinccart.tpl which contains the HTML template.
Can someone help me to find where I can do the toggle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the code of the master file of the module (`ps_shoppingcart.php`), you will see in the `hookHeader()` that the `ps_shoppingcart.js` is skipped when the option "**Ajax cart**" is turned off, so, you can remove these validation to keep the JS file loaded and in the file every time and now you can add your custom code, the code which show the popup is this:

```
if (resp.modal) {
  showModal(resp.modal);
}
```

Hope this help you!